# Foreach de java me sobre escribe los objetos

Tags: java, loops, java-ee, jpa

Amigos, tengo un foreach en java que recorre una lista para llenar otra y así enviarla a mi jquery, pero me he dado cuenta que el for me está sobreescribiendo los objetos.

Ej:

listadoMetodo(id)[0])=**'samsung'** y listadoMetodo(id)[0]) = 
**'iPhone 6'**

En la primera vuelta l_jQuery[0] = **'Samsung'**,

en la segunda vuelta l_jQuery[0] = **'iPhone 6'** y l_jQuery[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7KUkK.png) = **'iPhone 6'**. Les dejo unas imágenes y mi código. 
Saludos y gracias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/plain");
    HttpSession sesion = request.getSession(false);
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    int id_consumidor = Integer.parseInt(sesion.getAttribute("id_consumidor").toString());
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Producto producto = new Producto();
    List<Producto> lista = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Producto> l = productoFacade.oferta_guardadas(id_consumidor);
    productoFacade.oferta_guardadas(id_consumidor);
    for (Producto p : l) {
        producto.setNombreProducto(p.getNombreProducto());
        producto.setIdProducto(p.getIdProducto());
        producto.setPrecioNormal(p.getPrecioNormal());
        producto.setPrecioOferta(p.getPrecioOferta());
        producto.setRutaImagen(p.getRutaImagen());
        lista.add(producto);
    }
    String json = gson.toJson(lista);
    out.print(json);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Estás trabajando con la misma instancia asociada a la variable`Producto producto` y la estás agregando múltiples veces a la lista. Esto da la impresión de que sea siempre los mismos datos, y sucede que es el mismo objeto.

Basta con cambiar una línea de posición:

```
//recomendación: declarar las variables en su ámbito más cerrado posible
//Producto producto = new Producto();
List<Producto> lista = new ArrayList<>();
List<Producto> l = productoFacade.oferta_guardadas(id_consumidor);
productoFacade.oferta_guardadas(id_consumidor);
for (Producto p : l) {
    Producto producto = new Producto();
    producto.setNombreProducto(p.getNombreProducto());
    producto.setIdProducto(p.getIdProducto());
    producto.setPrecioNormal(p.getPrecioNormal());
    producto.setPrecioOferta(p.getPrecioOferta());
    producto.setRutaImagen(p.getRutaImagen());
    lista.add(producto);
}
```

Comment: Gracias, no me había dado cuenta. Te pasaste, bro :)